# Python type hints for a hashable, callable dataclass

Tags: python, python-typing, python-dataclasses

I want to write a Python function that takes `Callable` objects and corresponding arguments as input, and returns a mapping from the `Callable` objects to the values of these objects on the arguments. More concretely, the code might look something like the following.

```
>>> import collections
>>> import dataclasses
>>> from typing import Iterable, List, Mapping
>>> @dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
... class Adder:
...     x: int = 0
...     def __call__(self, y: int) -> int:
...             return self.x + y
... 
>>> def fn_vals(fns: Iterable[Adder], vals: Iterable[int]) -> Mapping[Adder, List[int]]:
...     values_from_function = collections.defaultdict(list)
...     for fn in fns:
...             for val in vals:
...                     values_from_function[fn].append(fn(val))
...     return values_from_function
... 
>>> fn_vals((Adder(), Adder(2)), (1, 2, 3))
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {Adder(x=0): [1, 2, 3], Adder(x=2): [3, 4, 5]})
```

However, I'm struggling to get this to work with a broader class of `Callable` objects. In particular, the following fails with an error saying that `__hash__` has not been implemented.

```
>>> import dataclasses
>>> from typing import Callable, Hashable
>>> class MyFunctionInterface(Callable, Hashable): pass
... 
>>> @dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
... class Adder(MyFunctionInterface):
...     x: int = 0
...     def __call__(self, y: int) -> int:
...             return self.x + y
... 
>>> Adder()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/alex/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/typing.py", line 814, in __new__
    obj = super().__new__(cls)
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Adder with abstract methods __hash__
```

I'd like to modify my `fn_vals` function so that `fns` has type `Iterable[MyFunctionInterface]` because the only properties that I need the elements of `fns` to have is that they be `Callable` and `Hashable`. Is there a way to indicate that a dataclass satisfies `MyFunctionInterface`, and have the `__hash__` function still be generated by the `dataclass` decorator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is a bad interaction between `abc` and class decorators.

Quoting the [`abc` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod),

> Dynamically adding abstract methods to a class, or attempting to modify the abstraction status of a method or class once it is created, are not supported.

Once a class is created, you're not allowed to change its abstractness (or at least, it's not allowed on the Python version you're on). Unfortunately, class decorators like `dataclasses.dataclass` kick in after the class is already created.

When `Adder` is initially created, it doesn't have a `__hash__` implementation. `abc` inspects the class at this point and determines that the class is abstract. Then, the decorator adds `__hash__` and all the other dataclass stuff to the class, but it's already too late.

Your class *does* have a `__hash__` method, but the `abc` mechanism doesn't know that.

---

As of Python 3.10, changing the abstractness status of a class now *is* allowed, if you call [`abc.update_abstractmethods`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.update_abstractmethods) on the class once you're done. The Python 3.10 version of `dataclasses` uses this to fix the problem you ran into. You're on 3.7, though. (3.10 wasn't out when this question was asked.)

---

As for how to proceed, there are three primary options. The first, now that 3.10 is out, is to update Python, but that doesn't work if you have to support versions below 3.9. The second option is to eliminate `MyFunctionInterface` entirely and just annotate your callable-hashable objects as `Any`. The third is, assuming you want your objects to specifically be callable with a single int argument and return an int, you can define a protocol

```
class MyProto(typing.Protocol):
    def __call__(self, y: int) -> int: ...
    def __hash__(self) -> int: ...
```

and then annotate your objects as `MyProto`.

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned in [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#dataclasses.dataclass)

> By default, `dataclass()` will not implicitly add a `__hash__()` method unless it is safe to do so. Neither will it add or change an existing explicitly defined `__hash__()` method. Setting the class attribute `__hash__ = None` has a specific meaning to Python, as described in the `__hash__()` documentation.

Looks like `Hashable` defines `__hash__` method so dataclass will not explicitly define `__hash__`. So create new class extending `MyFunctionInterface` and set `__has__ = None` and extend adder with that.

```py
import dataclasses
from typing import Callable, Hashable
class MyFunctionInterface(Callable, Hashable): pass

class MyFunctionInterfaceHashed(MyFunctionInterface):
    __hash__ = None

@dataclasses.dataclass(frozen=True)
class Adder(MyFunctionInterfaceHashed):
    x: int = 0

    def __call__(self, y: int) -> int:
        return self.x + y
```

Comment: `Hashable` doesn't define `__hash__`. The `dataclass` decorator adds `__hash__` to the class just fine, but it does so too late for `abc` to see it.

Comment: `MyFunctionInterfaceHashed` only hides the problem - with `MyFunctionInterfaceHashed`, subclasses can be instantiated even if they don't implement `__hash__` at all. [Here's an example.](https://ideone.com/a8P6gb)